# How do I make this input get put into an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been trying to have this SOP statement get read in to an array, but  I cant seem to get it. I'm a complete newbie at Java, so much help would be appreciated.

This is constructor that I'm trying to have the SOP statement in.

```
public class QuizScore 
{
private int qs[];
public QuizScore(int num)
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
        int[] qs=new int[num];
    }
```

This is the Main, if it is useful

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
    System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
    int num = d.readInt();
    new QuizScore(num);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `EasyReader` class in main is somehow taking the user input from an input stream. Another easily available class in java is `Scanner` which would let you get user input from the input stream.

You have to initialize your array before you can use it, before you loop and get the user input:

```
qs = new int[num];
```

Next, get the user inputs on individual scores and store them in the array with the appropriate index.

```
qs[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

**EDIT:** Tried to use [this](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jett/workshop2/code/EasyReader.java) implementation of `EasyReader` based on OPs query. Here is the complete class:

```
   public class QuizScore {
    private int qs[];
    static EasyReader console = new EasyReader();

    public QuizScore(int num) {

        qs = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
            try {
                qs[i] = console.readInt();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // console.ignore();
            }
        }
        console.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
        int num = console.readInt();
        new QuizScore(num);
    }

}
```

*Notice I catch an exception and ignore the user input when anything goes wrong - specifically when the user inputs a non-integer value.* - No longer valid since `EasyReader` seems to consume the invalid inputs.

Comment: this would be helpful, if my school didnt teach Java using EasyReader, so i have to learn it through that.

Comment: @user3030052 Okay, I tried to use [this](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jett/workshop2/code/EasyReader.java) implementation of EasyReader, see the edited code above

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the code as below.

```
int[] qs=new int[num];

for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
    qs[i] = num;
}
```

Comment: I put this in, but after i input how many integers there are, it gives me that many "Enter in your scores" and wont let me enter in the number.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class QuizScore 
            {
            private int qs[];
            public QuizScore(int num)
            {
                int[] qs=new int[num];
                for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");

                    qs[i]=i;//putting values in array;
                }
             }
```

Comment: with your solution, the array will be reinitialized in each incrementation of the for loop... Take out of the loop the int[] qs=new int[num];

Comment: I put this in, but after i input how many integers there are, it gives me that many "Enter in your scores" and wont let me enter in the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");  
int[] qs=new int[num];  
Scanner inputScores = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
      qs[i] = inputScores.nextInt();
    }
```